# TODO or FIXME features in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

simple Question, I find it easier to do a //FIXME //TODO in a document than Click Review -> New Comment -> Type the comment then go back to the document. Is there a way I can do this without clicking anything ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Word: File → Options → Customize Ribbon → press "Customize..." button next to "Keyboard shortcuts".

Here you can add keyboard shortcut for pretty much anything. In my case (Slovenian version) there was already a shortcut for adding a comment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). In English version of Word 2007 the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

This is for Word 2007, in older versions it's similar, although you will have to find the option under a different group (Insert if I remember correctly).

To get back to the document when you finish writing the comment just press ESC.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+M works for Microsoft Word 2010 as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Word 2007, Alt+R -> C will add a comment.  Haven't found a way to avoid a click to get back to the original document.

Comment: I agree, I tried Ctrl + sh + tab, ctrl + everything. 

it'll be nice if there were features like //comment or //reword or //hide_from_all_but_me

Comment: You can get back from the comment to the original document with "ESC".